# Filtering an array of dictionaries that contains a particular keyword

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I am retrieving data from the server,a search functionality is used.The data is an array of dictionaries like

```
{
 text : Some simple text,
 searchword : Apple text with new features,
 keyword : Normal words
 }
{
 text : Random,
 searchword : Newly generated text,
 keyword : Normal words
}
{
 text : Some simple word,
 searchword : Latest version,
 keyword : Normal words
}
```

I need to filter out like for any keys in all dictionaries if value contains "text"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in initialArray) {
    NSMutableDictionary *filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *text = (NSString *)obj;

        if ([text rangeOfString:@"text"].location == NSNotFound) {
            [filteredDictionary addObject:obj forKey:key];
        }
    }];

    [filteredArray addObject:filteredDictionary];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is very simple just assuming that below is your array of dictinary:-

```
for (NSDictionary *dc in yourArr)
{
    NSArray *yourArr)=[dc allValues];
    for (i=0; i<[arry count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[yourArr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"text"])
        {
            NSLog(@"found");
        }
    }
}
```